# target specific variable value changed but not working in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to create a Makefile where release build object files and program are generated in a ./build directory and debug build object files and program generated in a ./debug directory.

To achieve this I am using the target-specific variable values feature of make as per https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific

But the feature is not updating the directory to store the .o and program for some reason.

Makefile is below.  When I run the command:
make

then the release build is correctly created in the ./build directory.

But if instead I run :
make debug

then the .o and program file is generated also in the ./build directory?  Why is the directory not updated in the line:

debug: BUILD_DIR = ./debug

Here is the Makefile

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -std=c++17 -Wextra -Wconversion
PROJECTNAME=ntpserver
SOURCES = main.cpp select-server.cpp ntp-server.cpp address.cpp
BUILD_DIR = ./build

OBJ = $(SOURCES:%.cpp=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(PROJECTNAME): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@


debug: CPPFLAGS += -DDEBUG
debug: CXXFLAGS += -g
debug: BUILD_DIR = ./debug
debug: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(PROJECTNAME)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(BUILD_DIR)/*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) says, target-specific variable values are available in the target's *recipe,* not the target's *prerequisite list.*

There are two approaches you can choose from. The simpler one is to use Recursive Make, but that may cause trouble later, so I advise against it.

The more tedious but maintainable way is to create a parallel to `build`:

```
DEBUG_DIR := ./debug
DEBUG_OBJ = $(SOURCES:%.cpp=$(DEBUG_DIR)/%.o)

$(DEBUG_DIR)/$(PROJECTNAME): $(DEBUG_OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

debug: $(DEBUG_DIR)/$(PROJECTNAME)

$(DEBUG_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

(Once you have that working properly, you should consider moving the debug-specific compiler flags to the object pattern rule.)